# How to make groups for pdsh?

Tags: cluster-computing

my pdsh can only read /etc/genders for grouping, but I dont know how to generate a genders file for it. I prefer to use dsh style group files(/etc/dsh/group/nodes) for it, but the module dshgroup can not be activated.
I am in Debian 7:

```
$ uname -r
Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2
$ pdsh -L
4 modules loaded:

Module: rcmd/exec
Author: Mark Grondona <mgrondona@llnl.gov>
Descr:  arbitrary command rcmd connect method
Active: yes 

Module: misc/genders
Author: Jim Garlick <garlick@llnl.gov>
Descr:  target nodes using libgenders and genders attributes
Active: yes 
Options:
-g query,...      target nodes using genders query
-X query,...      exclude nodes using genders query
-F file           use alternate genders file `file'
-i                request alternate or canonical hostnames if applicable
-a                target all nodes except those with "pdsh_all_skip" attribute
-A                target all nodes listed in genders database

Module: rcmd/rsh
Author: Jim Garlick <garlick@llnl.gov>
Descr:  BSD rcmd connect method
Active: yes 

Module: rcmd/ssh
Author: Jim Garlick <garlick@llnl.gov>
Descr:  ssh based rcmd connect method
Active: yes 

$ cat /etc/pdsh/machines
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.101

$ cat /etc/dsh/group/nodes
10.0.0.101

$ pdsh -a uptime
no remote hosts specified
$ pdsh -g nodes uptime
no remote hosts specified

$ ls -l /etc/genders 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Nov  3 19:49 /etc/genders
```

/etc/genders is empty, because I don't know how to generate.

if I delete /etc/genders:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/genders
$ pdsh -a uptime
/etc/genders: error opening genders file
```

how to make pdsh to read dsh style group files?

Answer (score 2):

Try these links they have sample genders files & parsing checks..

https://web.archive.org/web/20150915154542/https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/genders.html (archive.org copy; original link is dead)
https://web.archive.org/web/20150201063434/http://www.phillippadgett.com/blog (archive.org copy, original site is dead)

To get dshgroup module installed, you'll have to compile pdsh yourself. I think the apt package maintainer didn't enable ALL modules by default. May be you can file a bug with him.

Comment: The phillippadgett page is gone. There's an archive page here (scroll down to the "Server Configuration Files" post): https://web.archive.org/web/20150201063434/http://www.phillippadgett.com/blog

Answer (score 0):

pdsh is still a powerful tool.
As most refences seem to have vanished,
I thought I'd do a sample file here for all of us.

```
node001 gpu,compute,randomgroup
node002 compute,randomgroup
```

You can now pdsh across nodes using the groups **gpu,compute** or **randomgroup**.

Comment: which file you are referring it? is this /etc/genders ?